# algo complexity - ever dwindling value from a series of integers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

we have this code

```
public int everDwindling(int m, int[] n) {
    
    int pass = 0;
    int[] seq = new int[m];
    int ind = 0;
    boolean isAllZero = false;
    while(ind < n.length || !isAllZero) {
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < m && ind < n.length ; i++) {
            if(seq[i] == 0) seq[i] = n[ind++];
        }
        
        int curMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++) {
            if(seq[i] < curMin && seq[i] > 0) curMin = seq[i];
        }
        
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++) {
            seq[i]-=curMin;
            sum+=seq[i];
        }
        
        if(sum == 0) isAllZero = true;

        pass++;
        
    }

    return pass;
    
}
```

so, this function wants to keep reducing the value of all integers and counts how many passes it needs to achieve that. Elements inside n is guaranteed to be greater than 0 and less than 2 billion. In my mind, the time complexity of this function is O(m*n.length), is this correct? and if not, could anyone elaborate? I'm always confused if `pass` is going to affect time complexity calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst case time is when the number of passes is maximised. This is when `n.length` is greater than `m` and in each pass (except the first) there is only one execution of `ind++`.

After the first pass, `ind` will be equal to `m`. After that `ind` increases with just one in each pass in the worst case. So then the number of passes is then `n.length - m + 1`.

As each pass has a time complexity of `O(m)`, that makes the worst case time complexity `O((n.length - m + 1)*m) = O(n.length*m)`

The best case is when there is just one pass. This happens when `m` is greater or equal to `n.length`. In that case the complexity is `O(m)`.

Comment: it's also possible that in case of duplicate integers in n, ind will increase more than 1 in each pass, will this affect complexity calc?

Comment: Yes, that will make it less "worse" as it reduces the number of passes in a "cheap" way, bringing it somewhere between the worst and best cases that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: just want to confirm again, `pass` is completely irrelevant in complexity calc, right? so, it doesn't matter how many `pass`, the worst case will always be O(m*n.length)?

Comment: The worst number of passes is why there is `n.length` in the expression. The number of passes is not an *input*, so it cannot appear in the expression, but the number of passes follows from the input.